# Issue with script look at the website

Tags: php, ajax

I could not find this problem anywhere and nothing really related that I can see. I have a URL Shortening script that I purchased, this script works great on my first server, installed the database, FTP'd the files and was all set and shortening URLs.

But since  then I moved it to a VPS server, I setup the server exactly same, with Centos 5.6. Installed the script, everything is fine. But the only thing that I find that does not work is the shortening process. I have no idea why it won't work. I have little knowledge of Ajax and JavaScript which I think the problem is with.

Here is ajax.php

```
 <?php
require_once '../config.php';

function url_exist($url)
{
    $c=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    if(!curl_exec($c)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function shorteURLFromID ($integer)
{
    $base = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $length = strlen($base);
    $out = '';

    while($integer > $length - 1)
    {
        $out = $base[fmod($integer, $length)] . $out;
        $integer = floor( $integer / $length );
    }
    return $base[$integer] . $out;
}

if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
    $l_type = (string) $db->escape(trim(strip_tags($_POST['type'])));

    $url = trim(strip_tags($_POST['url']));
    $url = str_replace(array("http://"), array(''), $url);

    if(strlen($url) < 3) {
        print '<style>.alert-300{width:325px;margin-left:182px;}</style>';
        die("<div class='alert alert-error alert-300'>".translate('empty_url_error')."</div>");
    }

    if(stristr($url, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
        print '<style>.alert-300{width:325px;margin-left:182px;}</style>';
        die("<div class='alert alert-error alert-300'>".translate('same_site_error')."</div>");
    }

    if(url_exist($url))
    {
        //check if exists for this user
        $rs = $db->get_row("SELECT string FROM links WHERE uID = '".$usersObject->ID()."' AND 
                            destination = '".mysql_real_escape_string($url)."' LIMIT 1");
        if(count($rs)) {
            $string = $rs->string;
            print "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$string;
        }else{
            $rs = $db->query("INSERT INTO links (destination, added, ip, uID, type) VALUES 
                            ('".$db->escape($url)."', '".time()."', '".ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', 
                            '".$usersObject->ID()."', '".$l_type."')");
            if($rs) {
                $string = shorteURLFromID($db->insert_id);
                $rs = $db->query("UPDATE links SET string = '$string' WHERE linkID = '".mysql_insert_id()."'");
                print "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$string;
            }else{
                print '<style>.alert-300{width:325px;margin-left:182px;}</style>';
                print "<div class='alert alert-error alert-300'>Could not create shortened link ".mysql_error()."</div>";
            }
        }

    }else{
        print '<style>.alert-300{width:325px;margin-left:182px;}</style>';
        print "<div class='alert alert-error alert-300'>".translate('invalid_url_error')."</div>";
    }
}else{
    print '<style>.alert-300{width:325px;margin-left:182px;}</style>';
    print '<div class="alert alert-error alert-300">'.translate('invalid_url_error').'</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: well maybe you can show us the code that is not working

Comment: If you click the URL text box, you get a JS warning: _Empty string passed to getElementById()_. Fix that first `:)`

Comment: The error is coming back from `/ajax.php`, so post the relevant part of that into your question, or on a Pastie if it is lengthy.

Comment: any ideas? I still cannot find out why this is not working, It worked fine before :( I even reinstalled it. And reinstalled Centos...

Comment: @Blackhawk1xx did you by chance try my answer below? Without being able to put debug code in, it appears the issue is with something in cURL that changed between the different PHP version.

Comment: I just added that code in there, didn't seem to change anything, I also do not know much about php at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in this option:

> curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

It looks like the default was changed with cURL 7.10 to true, so it is possible PHP 5.2.17  was using a version prior to 7.10.

Levi

Comment: Still says same error :( I have the website available again, I just did a fresh install cause the script owner said he would not look at it id I modified it with logo and all... But now I have it all setup again like normal cause I want to try and fix it, but added this curl into the ajax.php but it still giving me this error. I also if it makes and difference I have http://bitlink.it/info.php that you can look at

Comment: LEVI YOU, gave me the right path, the problem was PHP.ini had the curl disabled, here is the link of code I had to change exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,show_source

I changed the following line in php.ini to:

disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,show_source

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind without further info (or source of the script) is the version of PHP you're using. Is it different than that of the old server? If so, is it pre-5.2?

Comment: The other server was using 5.2.17, I believe I have the latest updated PHP 5